# Trying vs Just trying

Tags: word-usage

I've noticed you tend to say "just trying" when asked what you're doing. Would that work with 'just' omitted?

A: What are you doing, Tom?
B: Just trying to cook something.

A: What are you doing, Tom?
B: Trying to cook something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would still work if you omit "just".

It's strange, but "just" used here infers a casualness around the action.